# sticky footer issue on specific page?

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I am bumping my head against the wall about 4 hours now, and I can't find why the footer won't stick on bottom on this page:

http://www.agrampeli.com/newsite/articles.php?artid=94&msg=cform

Anyone can tell me what on earth I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Zoran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#wrapper1{
    ...
    padding-bottom: 170px;    
}
#wrapper3 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #BC141A;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

#footer {
    width: 960px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #8D0308;    
}
```

Comment: With its markup, it will not work if the content is > to body height : he must also set the body height from height : 100% to min-height : 100% .

Comment: Almost...plese,see the result:http://www.agrampeli.com/newsite/articles.php?artid=94&msg=cform   since I don't want my footer to be 100% width, I have removed that, but...I can't fix that now.

Comment: position absolute had another negative effect, my wrapper3 div is not appearing now.

Comment: maybe this contains useful information: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Comment: Sorry! position must be fixed... :D than it will be always at the bottom, I'll rewrite my answer!

Comment: Its OK now? I have tested it and works! Be sure that wrapper3 has position: fixed; bottom: 0; properties